# Javascript - not able to parse the JSON or string sent via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

How do i get the json data in Javascript?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$result=curl_exec ($ch); // it has json data 

curl_close ($ch);

/* PHP unit test - shows the data is available and it works 
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($obj as $k=>$v) {
  echo $k . ' ' . $v  . '<br/>';
}
*/

/* But, from PHP i need to send the data to Browser on Ajax/GET request*/
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
echo $obj;
//if i do not use json_decode and only do echo $result; then still
//javascript is unable to parse the json
```

So when Javascript is calling that PHP method, its failing to decode as readable format:

```
$.get(submit_url + '/login?', {
  code_please: '007',
}, function(data_please) {

  // ------------------------------FAIL to READ 
  alert(data_please);
  alert(data_please[0]);
  alert(data_please.id);
  //var duce = jQuery.parseJSON(data_please);
  //var art1 = duce.email;
  //for(oooi in data_please.db) { data_please.db[oooi].id++ } 

});
```

**Output:** Array

Comment: have you tried serializing the data?

Comment: What do you mean? is it not serialised already? while using json_decode on php?

Comment: Use `json_encode()` to produce a JSON string from a PHP array, not `json_decode()`.

Comment: `json_decode` converts a JSON *string* into a PHP array.  When you try to `echo` an array, you get the string `"Array"` (and an "array-to-string conversion" warning).  What exactly are you trying to do?  If you are trying to send it to a JavaScript AJAX call, then you can just `echo $result`, no need to decode it in PHP.

Comment: Show the actual response your server code is sending, eg via `console.log(data_please);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your getting a JSON encoded string from the curl response you don't need to call `json_decode` on it, just echo the string out. `json_decode` will convert it into a PHP array which is not what you want.

Also you should call your own endpoint using `$.getJSON` as this will convert the JSON into an object you can use with javascript automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You want to retrieve JSON data, but you use `json_decode()` on the  data you want - this turns the JSON data into a PHP array. Don't do that!

**Also**, you're not parsing the JSON in the JavaScript function, so the JS can't understand the response as a JSON object - it's just a string.

PHP:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch); // it has json data 
curl_close($ch);
exit($result);
```

JS:

```
$.get(submit_url + '/login?', {
  code_please: '007',
}, function(data_please) {
  var json = $.parseJSON(data_please);

  console.log(json);
  console.log(json[0]);
  console.log(json[0].id);
  //etc...      
});
```